# PYTHON Sort list with empty, string and numeric values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I want to sort short list like:

```
# we can have only 3 types of value: any string numeric value like '555', 'not found' and '' (can have any variation with these options)
row = ['not found', '', '555']
```

to

```
# numeric values first, 'not found' less prioritize and '' in the end
['555', 'not found', '']
```

I trying use

```
row.sort(key=lambda x: str(x).isnumeric() and not bool(x))
```

but it's not working

How can I sort it? (numeric values first, 'not found' less prioritize and '' in the end)

Comment: You stated the basic problem quite clearly: the order you want is not what `sort` supports, yet you somehow expect `sort` to do what you want.  You need to define your own key function to produce the priorities as you define them.  Alternately, filter the list into the three groupings you specify, sort each grouping, and concatenate the results.

Comment: I have added I solution with a function for sort(key=func)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def custom_sort(list):
    L1 = []
    L2 = []
    L3 = []
    for element in list:
        if element.isnumeric():
            L1.append(element)
        if element == 'Not found':
            L2.append(element)
        else : L3.append(element)
    L1.sort()
    L1.append(L2).append(L3)
    return L1
```

Comment: You can't do `L1.append(L2).append(L3)`. Anyway, I think what you are actually trying to do here is `L1.extend(L2); L1.extend(L3)`.

Comment: Actually didn't tried that. I amswered that from my smartphone. But thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorting non numeric values per ask

```
ar = [i for i in row if not i.isnumeric()]
ar.sort(reverse=True)
row = [i for i in row if i.isnumeric()] + ar
```

Comment: This solution actually doesn't take into account the fact that `'not found'` should outrank `''` in the sorted list.

Comment: @AdamBoinet right. I added that as a comment in one of the comments

Answer (score 0):

This will sort your list and give `'not found'` a higher priority than `''`:

```py
l = [int(a) for a in row if a.isnumeric()] # Or float(a)
l.sort()
row = [str(a) for a in l] +\
    ['not found'] * row.count('not found') +\
    [''] * row.count('')
```

Comment: Or, even faster for the latter part:

['not found'] * row.count('not found') + [' '] * row.count(' ')

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick too:

```
row = ['not found', '', 555, 1, '5' , 444]
print(row)

def func(x):
    if str(x).isnumeric():
        return  1/-int(x) # ordering numerics event if they are strings 
    elif str(x) == 'not found':
        return  2
    elif str(x) == '':
        return  3

row2 = row.sort(key=func)

print(row)
```

Results:

```
['not found', '', 555, 1, '5', 444]
[1, '5', 444, 555, 'not found', '']
```